# Why does my installation of box2d fail even though I already have swig installed

Tags: box2d, openai-gym

Requirement already satisfied: gymnasium[box2d] in c:\python\lib\site-packages (0.29.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.0 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from gymnasium[box2d]) (1.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle>=1.2.0 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from gymnasium[box2d]) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.3.0 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from gymnasium[box2d]) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: farama-notifications>=0.0.1 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from gymnasium[box2d]) (0.0.4)
Collecting box2d-py==2.3.5 (from gymnasium[box2d])
Using cached box2d-py-2.3.5.tar.gz (374 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pygame>=2.1.3 (from gymnasium[box2d])
Obtaining dependency information for pygame>=2.1.3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/61/93ae7afbd931a70510cfdf0a7bb0007540020b8d80bc1d8762ebdc46479b/pygame-2.5.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata
Using cached pygame-2.5.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata (13 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: swig==4.* in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from gymnasium[box2d]) (4.1.1)
Using cached pygame-2.5.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (10.8 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: box2d-py
Building wheel for box2d-py (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for box2d-py (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [21 lines of output]
Using setuptools (version 68.2.2).
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Box2D
copying library\Box2D\Box2D.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Box2D
copying library\Box2D_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Box2D
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Box2D\b2
copying library\Box2D\b2_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Box2D\b2
running build_ext
building 'Box2D._Box2D' extension
swigging Box2D\Box2D.i to Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp
swig.exe -python -c++ -IBox2D -small -O -includeall -ignoremissing -w201 -globals b2Globals -outdir library\Box2D -keyword -w511 -D_SWIG_KWARGS -o Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp Box2D\Box2D.i
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
File "", line 88, in *run_code
File "C:\python\Scripts\swig.exe_*main**.py", line 4, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'swig'
error: command 'C:\python\Scripts\swig.exe' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for box2d-py
Failed to build box2d-py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for box2d-py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

---stuck here, any suggestion welcome! thanks a lot

when I ran the command as 'pip install gymnasium[box2d]', the error pop up